# Delete From DynamoDB Via Secondary Index

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

If I have an a list of items in a table, that are related to a master item in another table, and the identifier for the master items comes from the field in the first table, and it is indexed, is there a way to delete all those items with one call, rather than doing a query using the index, retrieving all the items, then looping through them one after another and deleting by the hashkey? We are using node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property) to delete up to 25 items at once. But you still need to run a query before to retrieve the items you want to delete.

Comment: That's what I figured. I kept looking, but, oh well. Be a nice addition for them to add at some point.